# Indicate user feature uses fake data

Tags: usability, preview

My application has a 'templates' and a 'dashboards' pages. In the first one user can create dashboard templates containing charts, in the second one he can select a template and apply filters on it to display dashboards using his data.

In the template creation I use fake data in charts so the user can have a preview of how it will look like in dashboards. The problem is users tend to believe they are directly seeing their real data in the template page.

I wanted to add a 'PREVIEW' watermark on each tile of the template. Is it relevant or is there a better solution?

Comment: Is the "preview" of the chart a full size representation of the chart?

Comment: Yes, charts are displayed the same way in dashboard and templates.

Comment: Ok - one more question - in the template creation step, does the user configure properties and/or settings for the chart, prior to triggering viewing a preview? For example, name the axis, identify the data source, etc.

Comment: Is there no way to instead work with the users' actual data? Since the user feels this is what's happening anyways, maybe you should embrace that instinct.

Comment: @Splatz User creates his template and then adds charts into it. Chart creation opens a modal where he can configure his chart parameters. This modal also contains a live preview of the chart. When he finished to configure chart, it is added to the template. There is no concrete preview action like a 'preview' button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think using words like "Preview" or "Sample" are familiar to users and therefore your dummy data will be recognised as such.

The other approach you could use instead of or in addition to the above is to use labels/values that clearly make it obvious. For example, John Doe and Jane Doe make it obvious, as would XYZ Wizard Corporation or Acme Corporation.